# Regular Expression shouldn't match 1.00 but matches 1.10

Tags: asp.net, regex

I have an expression:

```
^(?:\d+\.?|\.?\d{2})$
```

I want it to match anything like this:

```
1.00
999999.00
```

I don't want it to match this:

```
1.10
1.01
1.02
```

How can I amend this regular expression? I've been at this for a while and I can't figure it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a negative lookahead like below,

```
^(?!.*\.00$)(?:\d+\.\d{2})$
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/rX5eE5/2)

Your regex `^(?:\d+\.?|\.?\d{2})$` is wrong, it won't match even the numbers like `1.10`

**Update:**

```
^\d+\.00$
```

If you want to make the decimal part as optional then try this,

```
^\d+(?:\.00)?$
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/rX5eE5/3)

Comment: I apologies I want the actual opposite to occur.